# React router - How to redirect to child component if parent component path is entered in url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I would like to redirect my url for e.g to '/questions/1' when I only write /questions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can render a redirect from one path to the other.

If using `react-router-dom` v5 use the `Redirect` component:

```
<Redirect from="/questions" to="/questions/1" />
```

If using `react-router-dom` v6 use the `Navigate` component:

```
<Route path="/questions" element={<Navigate to="/questions/1" replace />} />
```

Comment: This is perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but thought this might be useful to someone.

```
createBrowserRouter([
    path: 'auth',
    children: [
        {
            index: true,
            loader: async () => redirect("/auth/login")
        },
        {
            path: "login",
            element: <Login />
        },
    ]
)]
```

> ### !!! Warning
>
> This might cause redirect loops, check if one redirect isn't calling another if that happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to use index route in react-router-dom v6

Must be like the following -

```
 <Route path="parent" element={<Parent />}>
    <Route index element={<Child1 />} />
    <Route path="child1" element={<Child1 />} />
    <Route path="child2" element={<Child2 />} />
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if you want also to render parent. This renders "Today" in the AppPage when you enter URL "/app" and redirect you to "/app/today".

```
{

    path: "app",
    element: <AppPage />,
    errorElement: <NotFoundPage />,
    children: [
        {
            index: true,
            element: <Navigate replace to={'today'} />
        },
        {
            path: "today",
            element: <h1>Today</h1>,
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).